# What are these type of connectors called?

Tags: identification, connector, surface-mount

This thing is called a Plux22. There is also a 16 and 21 pin variant aka 21MTC. It is a connector you find on model train decoders. I believe this is propriety design of one the model railway companies. I cannot find it JLCPCB anyways.

It is not just a normal female SMD connector. The mating male connector is inserted from the bottom and not from the top. There are holes in the board underneath the connector and the SMD leads do not obstruct them.
[image]

[image]

In this video you can see how 2 mating parts are fitted. The 21 variant is designed so you cannot accidently insert the 2 components in a wrong way.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoTE3OsnOVA&t=40s

Are there more connectors like this? And how are they called?

Comment: you'll need to measure the distance between the contacts. But this looks like a "low-profile pin header connector", which probably is made by multiple manufacturers, and all you need to find a compatible one is the contact pitch.

Comment: As well as "bottom entry" could be "bottom or top entry" so be careful with filters.

Comment: If you are looking for the manufacturer Part No its: BUCHS22. 2.54 mm Socket Header Bottom Entry.

Answer (score 6):

These are widely known as "bottom entry" and your component is a "2x11 (double row) bottom entry (SMD) (straight) socket strip". I can't tell the pitch, though 2mm is common.

Searching for "bottom entry socket strips" will give you the correct results.

Comment: From the photo it seems a low profile 2mm pitch part… also it's often found in the board-to-board catalog section. It's a commodity part but the B.E. variants are less common. Molex and Samtec most probably have these

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Samtec have them for sure because I've specified in a bunch of such 2mm bottom entry ones from them. I vaguely recall them supporting different heights too (mated height).

Comment: Samtec makes *everything* you can spec in their sheet. If you can ignore lead time and price, of course.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio They have super fast lead time at least for small quantities/pre-series. But they do bill you through the roof :) I like to specify them as reference then chase down a cheaper 2nd source for volume production.

Comment: "bottom entry" a.k.a. "though-board"

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to measure the distance between the contacts. But this looks like a "low-profile pin header connector", which probably is made by multiple manufacturers, and all you need to find a compatible one is the contact pitch.

I went ahead and to Digikey, went connectors->rectangular connectors->female, then selected all the characteristics I could see (2 rows, surface mount):

https://www.digikey.de/short/hmmr58zb

You now only have to select the right number of contacts (16 or 21/22) and the correct mating pitch.

Comment: Tnx, the keyword I was searching for seems to be "bottom entry". The 2nd in your link is a one of them and I can set the filters for bottom entry